# How do I route to same Blazor page with different id

Tags: routes, blazor

I have a page with the route `@page "/observation/{Id:int}"`. The page also contains Prev/Next navigation links so users can quickly switch between observations. When I click a link, the route updates in the browser, but the page does not reload. I would like to keep these as hyperlinks so users can open in a new tab, so I don't think using `NavigateTo` on click will work for me. How can I get the page to reload while still allowing users to open the link in a new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `Navigate` to the same page, you are not reloading the component, just re-rendering it. `OnInitialized{Async}` is not called.  `OnParametersSet{Async}` is.

This page demonstrates how to handle this:

```cs
@page "/"
@page "/Index/{Id:int}"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=Previous>Previous</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=Next>Next</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-primary m-2">@(_selectedData?.Name ?? "No Data Exists")</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Id { get; set; } = 1;

    private Data? _selectedData;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (this.Id != _selectedData?.Id)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            _selectedData = _myData.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == this.Id);
        }
    }

    private void Next()
    {
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo($"/index/{this.Id + 1}");
    }

    private void Previous()
    {
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo($"/index/{this.Id - 1}");
    }

    private List<Data> _myData = new()
    {
        new(1, "UK"),
        new(2, "France"),
        new(3, "Spain"),
        new(4, "Portugal"),
    };

    public record Data(int Id, string Name);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, although I'm not using `NavigateTo` for my previous and next so users can open the links in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this answer much since it causes a hard refresh of the page, but I got it to do what I needed by doing a `NavigateTo` when `OnLocationChanged`

```
[Inject] NavigationManager Navigator { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{        
    Navigator.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
}

private async void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Navigator.NavigateTo(e.Location, true);
}
```